# The expected number of inversions--From Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen

Tags: algorithm

Let A[1 .. n] be an array of n `distinct` numbers. If i < j and A[i] > A[j], then the pair (i, j) is called an inversion of A. (See Problem 2-4 for more on inversions.) Suppose that each element of A is chosen randomly, independently, and uniformly from the range 1 through n. Use indicator random variables to compute the expected number of inversions.

---

The problem is from exercise 5.2-5 in *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen. Here is my recursive solution:

> Suppose x(i) is the number of inversions in a[1..i], and E(i) is the expected value of x(i), then E(i+1) can be computed as following:
>   Image we have `i+1` positions to place all the numbers,  if we place *i+1* on the first position, then x(i+1) = i + x(i); if we place *i+1* on the second position, then x(i+1) = i-1 + x(i),..., so E(i+1) = 1/(i+1)* sum(k) + E(i), where k = [0,i]. Finally we get E(i+1) = i/2 + E(i).
>   Because we know that E(2) = 0.5, so recursively we get: E(n) = (n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2)/2 + 0.5 = n* (n-1)/4.

---

Although the deduction above seems to be right, but I am still not very sure of that. So I share it here.

If there is something wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Note that the question is different in the second edition of the book.

Comment: This and $n - 1$ similar questions (together with the answers) are $n$ reasons why stackoverflow should enable MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's right, but I think the proper way to prove it is to use conditionnal expectations :

for all X and Y we have : E[X] =E [E [X|Y]]

then in your case :

E(i+1) = E[x(i+1)] = E[E[x(i+1) | x(i)]] = E[SUM(k)/(1+i) + x(i)] = i/2 + E[x(i)] = i/2 + E(i)

about the second statement :

if :

E(n) = n* (n-1)/4.

then E(n+1) = (n+1)*n/4 = (n-1)*n/4 + 2*n/4 = (n-1)*n/4 + n/2 = E(n) +n/2

So n* (n-1)/4. verify the recursion relation for all n >=2 and it verifies it for n=2

So E(n) = n*(n-1)/4

Hope I understood your problem and it helps

Answer (score 27):

All the solutions seem to be correct, but the problem says that we should use indicator random variables. So here is my solution using the same:

```
    Let Eij be the event that i < j and A[i] > A[j].

    Let Xij = I{Eij} = {1 if (i, j) is an inversion of A

                        0 if (i, j) is not an inversion of A}

    Let X = Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=1 to n)(Xij) = No. of inversions of A.

    E[X] = E[Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=1 to n)(Xij)]

         = Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=1 to n)(E[Xij])

         = Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=1 to n)(P(Eij))

         = Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=i + 1 to n)(P(Eij)) (as we must have i < j)

         = Σ(i=1 to n)Σ(j=i + 1 to n)(1/2) (we can choose the two numbers in
                                            C(n, 2) ways and arrange them
                                            as required. So P(Eij) = C(n, 2) / n(n-1))

         = Σ(i=1 to n)((n - i)/2)

         = n(n - 1)/4
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Just to elaborate on the P(Eij) part: the total number of ways to fill in 2 spots given n numbers is n(n-1). Now assume all n numbers are sorted in ascending order. If you pick first number, you have the next (n-1) numbers as options for creating an inversion pair. If you pick the second, then you have the next (n-2) numbers as options, and so on. So total ways of creating inversions is (n-1) + (n-2) +...+2 + 1 = n(n-1)/2.

And so you have P(Eij) = {n(n-1)/2} / {n(n-1)} = 1/2

Comment: Too late I know, but another way of looking at the probability of P( Eij ) is there are two possiblities that A[i] > A[j] or A[i] <= A[j] so probability that A[i] > A[j] is 0.5, for all elements j < i it is sum of all such probabilities i.e. for i = 1, it is ( n - 1 ) * 0.5 , for j = 2, it is ( n - 2 )*0.5 hence for all n, it is Σ(i=1 to n)( n - i )*0.5

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178163/clrs-solution-seems-meaningless-as-one-line-make-me-skeptical

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is even simpler, IMO, although it does not use "indicator random variables".

Since all of the numbers are distinct, every pair of elements is either an inversion (`i < j` with `A[i] > A[j]`) or a non-inversion (`i < j` with `A[i] < A[j]`).  Put another way, every pair of numbers is either in order or out of order.

So for any given permutation, the total number of inversions plus non-inversions is just the total number of pairs, or `n*(n-1)/2`.

By symmetry of "less than" and "greater than", the expected number of inversions equals the expected number of non-inversions.

Since the expectation of their sum is `n*(n-1)/2` (constant for all permutations), and they are equal, they are each half of that or `n*(n-1)/4`.

[Update 1]

Apparently my "symmetry of 'less than' and 'greater than'" statement requires some elaboration.

For any array of numbers `A` in the range 1 through `n`, define `~A` as the array you get when you subtract each number from `n+1`. For example, if `A` is `[2,3,1]`, then `~A` is `[2,1,3]`.

Now, observe that for any pair of numbers in `A` that are in order, the corresponding elements of `~A` are out of order. (Easy to show because negating two numbers exchanges their ordering.) This mapping explicitly shows the symmetry (duality) between less-than and greater-than in this context.

So, for any `A`, the number of inversions equals the number of non-inversions in `~A`. But for every possible `A`, there corresponds exactly one `~A`; when the numbers are chosen uniformly, both `A` and `~A` are equally likely. Therefore the expected number of inversions in `A` equals the expected number of *inversions* in `~A`, because these expectations are being calculated over the exact same space.

Therefore the expected number of inversions in `A` equals the expected number of non-inversions. The sum of these expectations is the expectation of the sum, which is the constant `n*(n-1)/2`, or the total number of pairs.

[Update 2]

A simpler symmetry: For any array `A` of `n` elements, define `~A` as the same elements but in reverse order. Associate the element at position `i` in `A` with the element at position `n+1-i` in `~A`. (That is, associate each element with itself in the reversed array.)

Now any inversion in `A` is associated with a non-inversion in `~A`, just as with the construction in Update 1 above. So the same argument applies: The number of inversions in `A` equals the number of inversions in `~A`; both `A` and `~A` are equally likely sequences; etc.

The point of the intuition here is that the "less than" and "greater than" operators are just mirror images of each other, which you can see either by negating the arguments (as in Update 1) or by swapping them (as in Update 2). So the expected number of inversions and non-inversions is the same, since you cannot tell whether you are looking at any particular array through a mirror or not.

Comment: How do you know that the # of less than == the # of greater than? I don't think that saying that they are symmetric proves anything.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have added an update to elaborate. The intuition is simple, but formalizing it did take some effort to word precisely. Thanks.

Comment: Lovely idea with substracting. +1

Comment: Does this solution hold even for equality?? i.e. if not all elements in the array are distinct ??

Comment: @alphacentauri: Sort of. The symmetry still holds, but any pair of equal elements is neither an inversion nor a non-inversion. If you take the total number of pairs `n*(n-1)/2`, and subtract the number of equal pairs (depends on which elements are equal), you get twice the expected number of inversions.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler (similar to Aman's answer above, but perhaps clearer) ...

```
Let Xij be a random variable with Xij=1 if A[i] > A[j] and Xij=0 otherwise.
Let X=sum(Xij) over i, j where i < j

Number of pairs (ij)*:               n(n-1)/2
Probability that Xij=1 (Pr(Xij=1))): 1/2
By linearity of expectation**:       E(X) = E(sum(Xij))
                                          = sum(E(Xij))
                                          = sum(Pr(Xij=1))
                                          = n(n-1)/2 * 1/2
                                          = n(n-1)/4

*  I think of this as the size of the upper triangle of a square matrix.
** All sums here are over i, j, where i < j.
```

Comment: Basically you pick the pairs of i, j so that i < j. There are binom(n,2) of such pairs. Every pair can be in either two states. a[i] > a[j] or otherwise. So, you divide binomial by two.

Answer (score 1):

Using indicator random variables:

1. Let X = random variable which is equal to the number of inversions.
2. Let Xij = 1 if A[i] and A[j] form an inversion pair, and Xij = 0 otherwise.
3. Number of inversion pairs = Sum over 1 <= i < j <= n of (Xij)
4. Now P[Xij = 1] = P[A[i] > A[j]] = (n choose 2) / (2! * n choose 2) = 1/2
5. E[X] = E[sum over all ij pairs such that i < j of Xij] = sum over all ij pairs such that i < j of E[Xij] = n(n - 1) / 4