# Counting inversions to see if an array is partially sorted

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

The definition of a sorted array below is from Algorithm book by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.

> An array is partially sorted if the number of inversions is <= cN

Shouldn't there be a limit to how high c can be? Couldn't I technically make c = 1000000000 and now a lot of unsorted arrays would be counted as partially sorted when they shouldn't be? I know that setting a high c is not smart, but shouldn't be some kind of range?

Here is an example of a worst case.

```
D C B A
```

Inversion counts

1 (d, c)

2 (d, b)

3 (d, a)

4 (c, b)

5 (c, a )

6 (b , a)

For an array of size 4, 6 items. That's totally linear if c = 2 and 6 < 4*2

When do we hit the N^2 range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically there is an upper limit to `c` since you can have only so many inversions(i.e. `N(N-1)/2`).

The algorithm is generalized for `N` and `c` isn't a function of `N`, it is a constant. You need to determine `c` based on your requirement. Even if it is of the order of `N^2` for certain values of `N`, it is still a constant and will not be comparable to `N^2` for higher values. As such, there isn't a way to limit `c` in general.

Whenever you feel the urge to raise `c` to the proposed `N^2` order for a particular value of `N`, do it. Then keep `c` fixed and raise `N` by a few orders of magnitude. Then enjoy the luxury of calling a constant a constant regardless of how large it is.

**Update**

Typed the max inversions as `N(N+1)/2` instead of `N(N-1)/2`. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on my duplicate answer!

Comment: I like your answer better because I understand yours better as I just started learning about Algorithms. That one sentence "You need to determine c based on your requirement" to me means that there isn't some fixed formula, but something you decide when looking at the context.

Answer (score 2):

The expected number of inversions in a random permutation is *~n<sup>2</sup> / 4* (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804681/the-expected-number-of-inversions-from-introduction-to-algorithms-by-cormen), for example).

Sedgewick's book deals with asymptotic complexity, where the idea is that "things start to act the way stated for large-enough sizes". So, even taking the large *c* value from your question, *c << n / 4* for large enough values of *n*.

But then you ask what about small arrays. The thing is, you could ask that about any part of this field, not just permutations. For example, comparison-based sort is *Ω(n log(n))*, and say that for some specific implementation, it is exactly *30 n log(n) + 400*. However, for small enough values of *n*, *30 n log(n) + 400 < 5000000000000000000 * n*, so you could argue that sorting is linear for small enough arrays (with constant 5000000000000000000). That is true, but most people in the field do not find it very useful. (It's possible that this stems from the fact that CS deals with increasingly larger sizes as time goes on.)

Comment: +1 because this is analytical and just better. I need to learn how to be analytical. My next answer needs to have at least three dozen `0`s.

Comment: @galactocalypse How about making the number of 0s in your answers *Theta(n)*? :-)